# XML Stylesheet XSL, multiple structure for same item

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This is my part of xml:

```
<record>
   <BillNum>999</BillNum>
   <Item>Glasses</Item>
   <Price>100</Price>
</record>
<record>
   <BillNum>999</BillNum>
   <Item>Book</Item>
   <Price>50</Price>
</record>
<record>
   <BillNum>999</BillNum>
   <Item>Shoes</Item>
   <Price>500</Price>
</record>
```

Now, I want to write xsl for this xml, which could style it something like below:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Glasses</td>
            <td>100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Book</td>
            <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shoes</td>
            <td>500</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

for each BillNum.

Please help me, how can I write the required xsl?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use XSLT 2.0 or 1.0? And do you want to create a single table for all data or one table for each group of `record`s having the same `BillNum`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen XSLT 1.0, I want one table for each group of records having the same BillNum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a grouping problem that in XSLT 1.0 is solved using Muenchian grouping http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml with a key

```
<xsl:key name="bill" match="record" use="BillNum"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="NameOfParentOfRecordHere">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="record[generate-id() = generate-id(key('bill', BillNum)[1])]" mode="table"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record" mode="table">
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Price</td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('bill', BillNum)"/>
</table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="record">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Item | Price"/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Item | Price">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

Then set up the HTML document structure with a template like

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is giving correct table format in IE, but in Firefox it is showing in simple text format: ItemPriceGlasses100Book50Shoes500

Comment: Well I have posted snippets that need to incorporated in a full stylesheet that makes sure the browser knows you are creating HTML output, either by putting `<xsl:output method="html"/>` in there or by having a template creating a `html` root element. I will edit to show that as well.

Comment: Now firefox is showing correct table but Chrome is showing blank page :(

Comment: How are you loading the XML in Chrome? It has very strict security settings for files loaded from the file system that for instance disable the use of `<?xml-stylesheet?>`. So with Chrome make sure you load the XML documents over HTTP or start Chrome with lower security settings, otherwise it will never load the XSLT referenced in an XML document. Check its error console whether it shows anything explaining the blank page.

Comment: how can I calculate total price?

Comment: Using `sum(key('bill', BillNum)/Price)` in the template for the record will compute the sum of all Price elements of all items in a group.